# Error: "1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found" flutter dart error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build an app with some charts, and I started with [this](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple) example, but it doesn't have the first part that initiates the app, so I tried adding:

```
void main() {
  runApp(SimpleTimeSeriesChart());
}
```

but I get

> 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
> Try adding the missing arguments.

in the second line. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me explain what am I doing wrong and what is the solution? The message is pretty clear, but I don't know which argument I need to add. Also, can anyone point me to some documentation about this particular issue? Thank you!

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart'
as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(SimpleTimeSeriesChart());
}

class SimpleTimeSeriesChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List < charts.Series > seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList, {
    this.animate
  });

  /// Creates a [TimeSeriesChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory SimpleTimeSeriesChart.withSampleData() {
    return new SimpleTimeSeriesChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      // Optionally pass in a [DateTimeFactory] used by the chart. The factory
      // should create the same type of [DateTime] as the data provided. If none
      // specified, the default creates local date time.
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List < charts.Series < TimeSeriesSales, DateTime >> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 9, 19), 5),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 9, 26), 25),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 10, 3), 100),
      new TimeSeriesSales(new DateTime(2017, 10, 10), 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series < TimeSeriesSales, DateTime > (
        id: 'Sales',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.time,
        measureFn: (TimeSeriesSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample time series data type.
class TimeSeriesSales {
  final DateTime time;
  final int sales;

  TimeSeriesSales(this.time, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to pass the first argument since it's not optional `SimpleTimeSeriesChart(this.seriesList`

```
void main() {
  runApp(SimpleTimeSeriesChart([]));
}
```

You can read more about Dart parameters [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters)